# Autonumeric удалить лишние нули

Tags: javascript

Как удалить в autoNumeric в input дробную часть из лишних нулей
Параметр mDec добавляет дробную часть, но при снятии фокуса с элемента, если дробная часть отсутствует, то добавляются нули равные заданному параметру

Преобразовать нужно по примеру

1.22500 => 1.255

1.00 => 1

1.90 => 1.9

Хотелось бы, чтобы этот был какой нибудь параметр, а не вручную писать

Версия плагина 1.9.46

Comment: Попробуйте метод myval = myval.toString() должны уйти

Comment: хотелось бы что бы это был именно параметр

Comment: parseFloat(variable);

Comment: Нужны преобразования именно в input, при сбросе фокуса

Comment: parseFloat(variable) когда значение преобразовано, он ставиться опять в инпут, но там уже стоит параметр mDec, поэтому parseFloat(1,23000) -преобразуется снова в 1,23000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть такой параметр aPad: false

Answer (score 1):

Делаем функцию `onblur` и с помощью `parseFloat` округляем:

```js
(function() {
  document.querySelector('input').onblur = function() {
    if(/^[-0-9.,]+$/.exec(this.value)){
      this.value = parseFloat(this.value.replace(/\,/g, '.'));
    };
  };
})();
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Введите число">
```